# PhoneGap asp.net MVC 4 network error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova, runtime-error

I publish my asp.net MVC project with visual studio then zip it and upload (with default page index.html )to build.phonegap.com it build project without errors.Then i download .apk but when store to my android mobile devices it gives this error what should i do?

this is my published project folder

[folder](https://d37wxxhohlp07s.cloudfront.net/s3_images/845437/Untitled_inline.png?1358558295)

this is error : [error](https://d37wxxhohlp07s.cloudfront.net/s3_images/845419/719389926_inline.jpg?1358555294)

this is my index.html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "Home/Index"
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend you to go through phonegap documentation so you can understand properly what phonegap is and what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap expects only html. You can't upload asp.net (or any other technology for that matter) project and expect it to work.

I suggest reading the documentation, starting here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app